# Invalid Default Value for 'faillog_time' error during OpenSIS Installation

Tags: php

I am trying to install OpenSIS on my computer but I am getting an error "invalid default value for 'faillog_time'.

I am using wampserver and my production site runs locally on my computer(localhost). The following code is found in the index.php file in my installation folder. There must be something I am missing. Anyone who had the same problem and worked around this? Here's the code:

```
$faillog_time=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
//DBQuery("INSERT INTO login_records (USER_NAME,FAILLOG_TIME,IP_ADDRESS,SYEAR,STATUS) values('$_REQUEST[USERNAME]','$faillog_time','$ip','$DefaultSyear','Failed')");

DBQuery("INSERT INTO login_records (USER_NAME,FAILLOG_TIME,IP_ADDRESS,SYEAR,STATUS) values('".optional_param('USERNAME','',PARAM_ALPHAEXT)."','$faillog_time','$ip','$_SESSION[UserSyear]','Failed')");

$max_id = DBGet(DBQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM login_records"));
$m_id= $max_id[1]['MAX'];
if($faillog_time)
    DBQuery("UPDATE login_records SET LOGIN_TIME=FAILLOG_TIME WHERE USER_NAME='".optional_param('USERNAME','',PARAM_ALPHAEXT)."' AND ID='".$m_id."'");
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same error in OpenSis 6.1 . That is a mysql database error in the installation process. Tracing in mysql.log showed an error creating the login_records table:

From: install/OpensisSchemaMysqlInc.sql

```
CREATE TABLE login_records
(
  syear numeric(5),
  first_name character varying(100),
  last_name character varying(100),
  profile character varying(50),
  user_name character varying(100),
  login_time timestamp,
  faillog_count numeric(4),
  staff_id numeric(10),
  id INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  faillog_time timestamp,
  ip_address character varying(20),
  status character varying(50),
  school_id DECIMAL( 10 ) NULL,
 `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The failure is on the

```
faillog_time timestamp,
```

line which needs a default value. Looking at other timestamps in the file, they were set up with:

```
 NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

so I just added "default current_timestamp" to it, reran the installation and it worked fine.

```
 faillog_time timestamp default current_timestamp,
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Resolved it for me on a 6.2 install.